# Extending ngFor directive without the interface losing object typing

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In our application, every object has a unique ID associated with it. To help with rendering of the large lists we occur (of which, there are many), I have decided to utilize `trackby` functions for all templated `*ngFor` loops within our app.

I decided the best course of action to reduce duplication of the `trackby` functions, would be to create a custom `ngFor*` directive that does this automatically, if it finds that the object in question has an `ID` or has an index (business logic dictates this) it would add the custom trackby.

This does work, and the trackby gets added like I had hoped. However, when utilizing the custom `*ngFor` I noticed that the typing gets lost on the NgIterable object within the template and I'm not sure why, since I am extending with usages.

**Here is the custom directive:**

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  IterableDiffers,
  NgIterable,
  TemplateRef,
  TrackByFunction,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from "@angular/core";

import { NgFor, NgForOfContext } from "@angular/common";
import { InfiniteScrollItem } from "@shared/lists";

@Directive({
  selector: "[dpsNgFor][[dpsNgForOf]]",
  standalone: true,
})
export class DpsNgForDirective<T, U extends NgIterable<T> = NgIterable<T>> extends NgFor<T, U> {
  public _trackBy(index: number, item: any) {
    const _isScrollItem = (object: InfiniteScrollItem<T> | never) => "item" in object && "index" in object;
    const _hasId = (object: InfiniteScrollItem<T> | never) => "id" in object;

    // If it's an infinite scroll object, use the item.index;
    if (_isScrollItem(item)) {
      return item.index;
    }

    // Not an infinite scroll item
    if (_hasId(item)) {
      // Use the object id (if it has one).
      return item.id;
    }
    // Fall back to index if id isn't found natively in the object.
    return index;
  }

  @Input()
  set dpsNgForOf(value) {
    super.ngForOf = value;
  }

  @Input()
  set dpsNgForTrackBy(trackBy: TrackByFunction<T>) {
    super.ngForTrackBy = trackBy;
  }

  constructor(
    public _viewContainer2: ViewContainerRef,
    public _templateRef2: TemplateRef<NgForOfContext<T, U>>,
    public _differs2: IterableDiffers
  ) {
    super(_viewContainer2, _templateRef2, _differs2);
    super.ngForTrackBy = this._trackBy;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, or pointed in the right direction.

*Edit:* Here are some examples of what I mean, when referring to "interface typing is lost".

This is what it typically looks like when the interface has the proper typing with a regular ngFor
[image: Regular ngFor usage]

And this is what it looks like with the custom ngFor directive. Both accomplish the goal of iterating correctly. This one just lost the typing associated with the object.
[image: Custom ngFor usage]

Comment: Can you please tell us your Angular version? Would it be possible to reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui I don't think it would be possible to reproduce the issue in stackblitz, simply because I don't believe Stackblitz has templated interface typing. 

Angular version is: 15.1.2

Comment: I have added some images to help explain a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to set typing on the `value` variable so that it ended up looking like the following:

```
  @Input()
  set dpsNgForOf(value: U & NgIterable<T>) {
    super.ngForOf = value;
  }
```